# Flutter Android Plugin: PackageInstaller not showing pop-up for installing APK in background on Android 11

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, apk

I am working on a Flutter plugin for Android that facilitates the installation of APK files. Currently, I am using PackageInstaller to create a pop-up for the installation process. This approach works well on Android 10, where the pop-up appears even when the app is in the background.

However, I've noticed that on Android 11, the pop-up doesn't appear when the installation is triggered in the background. I'm not an Android expert, and I'm seeking guidance on how to address this issue.

Here is a simplified version of my code

```
      val apkFile = File(filePath)

      val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE)
      
      val apkFileUri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        context,
        context.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider",
        apkFile,
      )
      intent.data = apkFileUri

      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

      startActivity(context, intent, null)
```

Is there a specific change or additional step needed to make the pop-up appear on Android 11, even when the app is in the background? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.